# How to update observations with from 2 variables

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that looks like this in Stata:

| Place | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2000 |  |
| b | 2000 |  |
| c | 2000 | 100263 |
| a | 2001 | 100261 |
| b | 2001 | 100262 |
| c | 2001 | 100263 |
| a | 2002 |  |
| b | 2002 |  |
| c | 2002 |  |

I want the values to remain the same but be matched to a,b,c to all years so that it looks like:

| Place | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2000 | 100261 |
| b | 2000 | 100262 |
| c | 2000 | 100263 |
| a | 2001 | 100261 |
| b | 2001 | 100262 |
| c | 2001 | 100263 |
| a | 2002 | 100261 |
| b | 2002 | 100262 |
| c | 2002 | 100263 |

and if there is any place observation d that does not match anything, I would like it to return an NA. I tried using the `append` command.  but that won't work. Do you have any tips on how to do this?

Comment: NA could be a string value in Stata but has meaning only to the beholder. Missing string values and empty strings are one and the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `stripolate` from SSC.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str1 place int year str6 value
"a" 2000      ""
"b" 2000      ""
"c" 2000 100263
"a" 2001 100261
"b" 2001 100262
"c" 2001 100263
"a" 2002      ""
"b" 2002      ""
"c" 2002      ""
end

sort place year 

stripolate value year, groupwise by(place) gen(value2)

l , sepby(place)

     +--------------------------------+
     | place   year    value   value2 |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. |     a   2000            100261 |
  2. |     a   2001   100261   100261 |
  3. |     a   2002            100261 |
     |--------------------------------|
  4. |     b   2000            100262 |
  5. |     b   2001   100262   100262 |
  6. |     b   2002            100262 |
     |--------------------------------|
  7. |     c   2000   100263   100263 |
  8. |     c   2001   100263   100263 |
  9. |     c   2002            100263 |
     +--------------------------------+
```

Note that a corresponding solution for numeric variables would be

```
mipolate value year, groupwise by(place) gen(value2)
```

where `mipolate` is also from SSC.

Comment: My value2 is stored as a str5 since it is a census number and I am working on changing that right now since this code doesn't work, but I will update this thread again once I do!

Comment: It prints out a single number repeated for all observations. Could it be because I also have gaps in my place variables?

Comment: That shows the importance of following the advice in the Stata tag wiki and giving us a proper data example using `dataex`. I will revise my answer.  How can `str5` work for a 6 character string?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `merge`

```
// Get the value for each Place. We end up with a Place-level dataset
preserve
collapse (firstnm) updated_value = value, by(Place)
tempfile temp
save "`temp'", replace
restore

* Looks like this
* Place updated_value
* a 100261
* b 100262
* c 100263

// Merge the above data into the original data, based on Place
merge m:1 Place using "`temp'"
```